# (Java) How can I use Generic quickSort to sort multiple types (Integer, Double, String) at once? Is this possible?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, quicksort

I have created a quickSort program that reads strings from a file and then sorts them. Can my quickSort class/method be changed to accept Integers, Doubles, and Strings? Also, if it's not possible to sort all three at once, (admittedly, I can't conceptualize how it would accomplish this) can I at least sort the three types into separate lists? I'm really not sure where to begin.

- Edit: The 2nd code block is my implementation of the quickSort Class, and is likely the area of focus, but I decided to include the main file as well.

  ```
  /**
  This program tests the quickSort method in QuickSort class.
  NOTE: you will have to edit the file directory for the names file
  for the program to correctly run on your computer. This may be a
  side-effect of my decision to use FileInputStream to read the file
  but I could not find a simpler solution. 
   */


  /**
   *
   * @author JCD
   * 2/9/2017
   * 
   */
  public class QuicksortSuccessfulDraft{



  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

      // 
      int result;
      String input;
      String str;

      // new list declaration that will store the original 
      // unsorted name.txt file 
      List<String> unsorted = new LinkedList<>();


      // I decided to use DataInputStream and BufferedReader to read the
      // file directly. This proved to be the most elegant solution.
      // I had previously tried other options such as Scanner, but
      // ultimately chose this method instead.
      try
      {
          try (DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/C:/Users/jdavi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Names/src/names/names.txt"))) {
              BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));

              while ((str = b.readLine()) != null){
                  unsorted.add(str);
              }   }
      }
      //this ensures the program will throw an exception if the file
      // is not found in the given directory
      catch(IOException exp)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp.getMessage());
      }
      // creates a new String array called n that converts unsorted into
      // an array and stores the corresponding values. 
      String []n = unsorted.toArray(new String[unsorted.size()]);

      // This Dialogue box will show the names in the order they appeared
      // in the given file. I currently have this commented out to avoid
      // confusion w/ multiple dialog boxes popping up simultaneously.

      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, unsorted); 



      // quickSort is called and will sort String n
      // Will also print a dialogue box of the names in ALPHABETICAL order
      quickSort.quickSort(n);

      do
      {
        // Dialogue box that prompts the user to enter in a name to search
        // input must be in all caps
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Search for a name on the list (ALL CAPS): ");
                result = StringBinarySearcher.search(n, input);
                if(result == -1)
                {
                    // Dialogue box will pop up if the name is not found 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    input + " was not found.");           
                }
                else
                {
                    // Dialogue box will pop up if name was found
                    // Will tell user the element the name was located at 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + " was found at element " + result);
                }
                // Dialogue box will prompt the user to search again or exit
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
               "Would you like to search for another name (Y or N)?"
                       + " ");
      }
      //loops to the name search dialogue if the user answers Y or y
      while (input.charAt(0) == 'y' || input.charAt (0) == 'Y');
  }
  ```

  }

**IMPLEMENTATION BELOW**

```
/**
 * The quickSort class provides a public static method for performing a QuickSort on an String array
 */
public class quickSort {

  /**
   * quickSort method calls the qSort method to sort a String array.
   *
   * @param array is being sorted
   */
  public static void quickSort(String[] array) {
    qSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    // My attempt to change the Dialog box size to not extend
    // past the screen. Did not work as intended. :(
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(250, 250));
    // Dialogue box that shows the array sorted in ALPHABETICAL order
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(array));
  }

  /**
   * The qSort method uses the QuickSort algorithm to sort a String Array
   *
   * @param array
   * @param start the first subscript of the list being sorted
   * @param end the last subscript of the list being sorted
   */
  public static void qSort(String[] array, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
      // gets pivot point
      int q = partition(array, start, end);
      // sorts the left sublist
      qSort(array, start, q - 1);
      // sorts the right sublist
      qSort(array, q + 1, end);
    }
  }

  /**
   * this method selects a pivot value and arranges the array into 2 sublists. The values < the
   * pivot are stored on the left list and the values > or = are stored on the right.
   *
   * @param array being partitioned
   * @param start the first subscript of the area being partitioned
   * @param end the last subscript of the area being partitioned
   */
  private static int partition(String[] array, int start, int end) {
    //pivot value will be stored here for comparisons
    String x = array[end];
    // the left sublist position, for now
    int i = start - 1;
    // will be used to temporarily store a value
    String temp;
    for (int k = start; k < end; k++) {
      // scan list and move values that are < pivot point
      // to the left sub list
      if (array[k].compareTo(x) <= 0) {
        i++;
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
      }
    }
    //Swaps contents of two elements in the array
    temp = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = array[end];
    array[end] = temp;
    return (i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Just change methods with `String[]` parameters to, e.g. `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] array)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you for the timely reply. If I successfully implement it this way, how will my code determine where to put Strings in relations to Integers (for example). Worded more clearly: How does Java determine if Strings come before/after integers?

Comment: Oh, you want to sort a *mixed* array? In that case, you'd have to provide a custom `Comparator`. And it will get really gross and un-type safe.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes. And I will look into Comparators. Thanks again.

Comment: This is such a bad idea in general that I have to ask why you think it's necessary. For what reason would you want to mix data types in a single collection, and on what basis would you then compare them? What is the larger problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JimMischel I agree. But this is part of my college class. "This assignment simply requests that you take the quicksort algorithm that you have been working with and make it generic.  **You are to demonstrate the effectiveness of your work by defining a main method that passes a list of Integers, Doubles, and Strings and sorts them all.** 
Edit: It's possible that I may be misinterpreting the assignment. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible that you're misinterpreting the assignment. The writing is unclear, but the term "make it generic" makes me think that the first comment, by Andy Turner, is what you want to do. The other interpretation, that you're expected to sort an array containing `[27, "Foobar", 93.68]`, seems unreasonable.

Comment: @JimMischel Ah, that interpretation seems much easier. Once I have it all set up, would I simply call my generic quicksort method 3 separate times, then? Once for each Int, Double, and String list. Thank you again for your time.